# How to use Linq group a order list by Date

Tags: c#, linq

I have a order list and want to group them by the created date.

Each order's created datetime will be like "2010-03-13 11:17:16.000"

How can I make them only group by **date** like "2010-03-13"?

```
 var items = orderList.GroupBy(t => t.DateCreated)
 .Select(g => new Order()
 {
     DateCreated = g.Key

 })
 .OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderID).ToList();
```

**Update: How can I group order by month? And the following code is not correct.**

```
var items = orderList.GroupBy(t => t.DateCreated.Month)
 .Select(g => new Order()
 {
     DateCreated = g.Key

 })
 .OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderID).ToList();
```

Many thanks.

Comment: did you  finally find how to do that with year-month only?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Date property.

```
var items = orderList.GroupBy( t => t.DateCreated.Date )
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `.Date` will discard the time component, e.g.

```
var items = orderList.GroupBy(t => t.DateCreated.Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `t => t.DateCreate.Date`.